# ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './events/client'

Tags: javascript, npm, discord, bots

so this is my code

```
    //event handler
exports.run = (client, msg, args) => { 
    const  prefix = '-';  
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
        
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd);

    if(command) command.execute(client, message, cmd.  args, Discord);    
}
    if(command === 'pula'){
        client.commands.get('baned').execute(message, args);
    }
```

```
    //command handler
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of command_files){
const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
if(command.name){
client.commands.set(command.name, command);
} else {
continue;
}
}
}
```

```
//message.js
 exports.run = (client, msg, args) => { 
 const  prefix = '-';  ``
 if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

const command = client.commands.get(cmd);

if(command) command.execute(client, message, cmd.  args, Discord);    
}
  
}
```

```
   
   //ready.js
    module.exports = () => {
    console.log('S-a Trezit Lucreita!');

 `
```

And it just gaves me that error, i dont really know what to do, i beg you to help me!I searched on formus, did everything they said and it didnt work.I just tryed everything, i dont have even a clue, im just a noobie being honest and i hope that someone might help me

Comment: What error? Can you provide the error in your question and what you've done to try and fix it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './events/client'
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './events/client'